# ActionBar Tabs are Awkwardly Centered on Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, xamarin.android

I'm using ActionBarSherlock to manage my app's action bar. I've added 2 tabs which are linked to Fragments. No problem.

On a phone - in portrait, the tabs layout beneath the main action bar (as expected) and are equally spaced. Looks great. However, on a tablet - in portrait mode - the tabs layout beneath the main action bar, but are awkwardly centered:

[image: Screenshot of tabs]

I'd like to know how to fix this 2 ways:

1. How can I make the tabs align to the Left side of the parent activity and stay below the main action bar. I've seen a few apps do this.
2. [stop-gap] How can I space the 2 items out to fill the entire width?

**Note:** I mostly want to know how to implement version 1.

Comment: Another way is to use `ViewPager` and `ViewPagerIndicator`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the ViewPage a shot. Good call.